# apache xampp virtual host makes error 403 windows

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

I simply want to enable the test.php file to be accessible via a virtualhost so I added just `127.0.0.1 test.localhost` in the windows host file and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/Programmordner/test"
ServerName test.localhost
<Directory "D:/Programmordner/test">
require all granted
    
#<FilesMatch "^((test|test2).testdateiendung1|.+.testdateiendung2)$">
<FilesMatch "^(test.php)$">
    Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
```

in httpd-vhosts.conf

Now if I add the second, it seems I even cannot open the default documentation website by clicking the admin-button on the apache interface, which should not be affected? If I erase the second the alterations in the windows host file doesnt affect anything and I can access all files in standard htdocs. I switched different versions like allow from all, access denied access granted but nothing changed

If somebody knows there is already which solves my problem, I will not grudge him however I looked for it and it did not help

Comment: If you set the document root to `D:\Programmordner\test`, then `<Directory "D:Programmordner/test">` can hardly be correct, now can it?

Answer (score 0):

I made several fixes and changed to Port 80 (without httpS :( ) and everything is running now.